# Facebook post link not working on phones with FB app installed

Tags: facebook, deep-linking

I have a FB post with photo or video still can be simplified the URL to format `https://www.facebook.com/{pageid}/posts/{postid}`.

However lately I found such link, if opened from website in mobile browser (Chrome on Android or iOS) open a FB app, but that open app home, instead of opening that post.

I am trying to share URL from FB app in iOS, we got nearly the same URL type, but with some query parameters added like `?s=1803...&sfns=mo`.

And recently it even looks the post id I get there is different.

How can I get a proper shareable URL on pc? Sadly using the link on date published, and striping it to this basic format, does not work correctly any more (links to `fb.com/{pageid}/photos/{photoid}/{postid}` which can be stripped down to open in classic view to that first mentioned format....)

Is there a simple way to make it work OK on clicking onto smartphone? On desktop difference between full URL and simplified to basic ../posts/{postid} is that id does not open the theatre mode, but sometimes it's on purpose we want to open the post in that basic view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood - so I hope I'm addressing the correct question.

If you are asking "how to deep link into the FB app and have it opened in the correct place", then the answer is that deep linking into an app is quite different then navigating into a specific web page.

Apps are built differently and there are various methods of deep linking into a page, depends on how the app developer implemented deep linking, mobile platform and other factors.

In FB case, they probably need some query params populated with information that the developer can use in order to open the correct page in the app when it is opened via your click.

Moreover, the way to deep link depends on FB, and may change over time. e.g. they may use URI scheme like `fb://something...` but can always change that. I can't give a definitive answer on which scheme or deep link will work as it can be changed on any FB app update.

Comment: Well, issue is, how a correct URL of SHARED POST should look like, so if published on some website, it opens correct both on desktop, and also on smarthone in app, because now - it opens ok on desktop, but on FB app on smartphone it just opens my default home, not the post  of some page, as it should...

Comment: To achieve that you need to have some click server to handle the user-agent and according to that run the correct deep linking approach (either web redirect or mobile deep link)

Comment: click server? i hoped there is a direct correct way to get the correct link fast - everyone says click on published time, clear it and thats it, but that way on mobile can be problem, so found a way to go trough share, choose direct message, and in the shown preview copy the link from it...   but that should be more simple way to get that url????  thats nuts